# Cross checking against a range

Tags: excel

I have a datasheet with a series of numbers in a row (A1:E1), I also have a growing block of numbers in a defined name range (doesn't have to be a range). I want to check if all of the values in A1:E1 exist in the range with a simple TRUE or YES result or if they do not all exist then a simple FALSE or NO result. Fumbled around with a few IF/AND/MATCH formula combinations but can't seem to get it to work. Anyone ideas ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This array formula would check to see if all of the values in A1:E1 are in MyRange which has the test values.  As I indicated, it is an array formula so it needs to be entered with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(A1:E1,MyRange,0),0))>0
```

If all are found in MyRange it returns to TRUE.  If any are not in MyRange, it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND((COUNTIF(myRange,A1)=1),(COUNTIF(myRange,B1)=1),(COUNTIF(myRange,C1)=1), <<<ETC>>> ),TRUE,FALSE)
```